# Domain name change on Git Server

Tags: git, configuration, settings, git-config

seriously need help here.

Previosuly the domain name of my server is git.abc.com, but now gonna change the domain to xyz.com, means become git.xyz.com.

Any idea on how to change the configure? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your project open file `.git/config` and replace `git.abc.com` to `git.xyz.com`.

Your `.git/config` file should looks like:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git+ssh://git@git.xyz.com/project/repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

You also can run next command:

```
git remote set-url origin git+ssh://git@git.xyz.com/project/repo.git
```

Comment: But I see this only.

[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true

Comment: @user548682 Added `.git/config` file example.

Comment: my file does not show abc.com, it just shows /gitProject/abc.git only.

Comment: Sorry @VladimirKovpak, I didn't realize we were converging to the same answer until I submitted it -- at least they don't flag duplicate answers :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change a repository configuration on a local cloned mirror, you can do it with the following steps:

```
git remote # shows the remotes. we will pick "origin" for the example
git remote get-url origin # checks that this is indeed the correct remote URL
git remote remove origin # delete the remote from the remotes list
git remote add oringin <URL>
```

But this will break your push/pull configurations, and you will have to create them again. That's why there is an alternative:

```
git remote set-url origin <URL>
```

This will however require you to know two things:

- The remote name
- The remote URL

That's why I included the first part. If you are unsure of those, the first two commands should display them.

---

Note: if you are talking about server configuration, I can't help you without more information.